# Return another column's value based on an IF condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create the total column in Pandas. How it is calculated is as follows - If nb_months = 1 then take the trans_amt as the value if not set to 0.

| Trans_amt | Nb_months | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 12 |
| 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 24 | 9 | 0 |

df['Total'] = [df['Trans_amt   '] if x == 1 else 0 for x in df['nb_months']]

My code above returns the entire trans_amt series in the total column. Any help would be great.

Comment: Check `np.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Total'] = np.where(df['nb_months'] == 1,df['Trans_amt'] , 0)
```

syntax:

np.where(condition, True, False)

Comment: How would I have multiple conditions ? thank you

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.logic.html

Comment: np.logical_and() - and add those conditions inside

Comment: @HimansuOdedra - Check [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column).

Comment: Thank you -  is there anyway to groupby and sum by different columns. For example, total (based off of 1 month) total_1 (based off of 2 month) etc. Sum these columns and produce an array with account number and sum(total_1) and sum(total_2)

Comment: sure - there is function group_by - it's often used - also there is agg function:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html

Comment: If U provide your data as df - i can group it

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,123,123,123],
                   'trans_amt':[12,0,0,24], 
                   'Nb_months':[1,5,7,9]})

df['OL_FEE_1'] = np.where(df['Nb_months'] == 1,df['trans_amt'] , 0)
df['OL_FEE_3'] = np.where((df['Nb_months'] <= 3) & (df['Nb_months'] != 0) & (df['Nb_months'] > 0),df['trans_amt'] , 0)
df['OL_FEE_6'] = np.where((df['Nb_months'] <= 6) & (df['Nb_months'] != 0) & (df['Nb_months'] > 0),df['trans_amt'] , 0)

I need one row which has the ID and the sum of each of the OL columns: 12,12,12

Comment: grouped = df.groupby(['ID'])["OL_FEE_1", "OL_FEE_3", "OL_FEE_6"].sum()